# Duplicated singleton when using shared library

Tags: c++, singleton, shared-libraries, factories

I am trying to bind a shared library in Python using pybind11.

I created a simplified version, that illustrates the problem.
From python I call the function ***foobar***. 
This function calls a static function, that calls a factory, that again calls a factory, that constructs the Singleton.

This works fine when I run the code as a executable (without using the binder). 
The problem is that when the library is used with the binder through Python, the Singleton gets constructed twice (e.i, with every use of the Singleton).
Once in the constructor of ***Factory2*** and later in the ***foobar*** function.

I have already tried what other solutions here suggest by hiding the factories, but that didn't work or I might have implemented it wrong.

Any ideas on how this could be solved, so that the singleton only gets constructed once?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I created a small example that illustrates the problem.

Main.cpp:

```
int foobar(){
Singleton::createModel();
Singleton::getModel(); //SECOND CALL TO CONSTRUCTOR

return 0;
}
```

Singleton.h:

```
class Singleton {
public:

static void createModel(){
    Factory factory;
}

static void setModel(Model *model) {
    Singleton::getInstance().model = model;
}


static Model *getModel() {
    return Singleton::getInstance().model;
}


private:
static Singleton &getInstance() {
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}

Singleton() : model(nullptr) {};

~Singleton() {};

Model *model;
};
```

Factory.h:

```
class Factory {
public:
Factory(){
    Factory2 factory2;
 }
};
```

Factory2.h:

```
class Factory2 {
public:
Factory2();
};
```

Comment: Move implementations of methods to cpp files. Apparently compiler/linker creates two versions of `Singleton::getInstance` and as result you have  two instances of `static Singleton instance;`. Keeping code in cpp should resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works! I made a mistake first by not including the header file in the main, but the .cpp file instead. So then it didn't change anything, but now it all works as expected after I included the header instead.